# A combinatorial question involving two pairs of sums

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $l,m, n,p$ are four numbers chosen independently and with replacement from the set $\{0,1,2,\cdots,N \}.$ In how many ways can we have :
$$ l+m=n+p$$ 
**My attempt:** Fixing $l+m=i,0 \leq i \leq 2N,$ we have $n+p$ can be $i$ in $i+1$ ways. (For instance for  $i=2$,the partitions are $2=2+0=0+2=1+1.$) But in that case $l+m$ can itself be chosen in $i+1$ ways therefore that case, the number of ways for the given condition to hold is  given by:$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N}(i+1)^2=\frac{(N+1)(N+2)(2N+3)}{6}.$$ I want to know if my solution is correct. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For $n=1$, I get six ways ($(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(1,0,0,1),(0,1,1,0),(1,0,1,0),(1,1,1,1)$), but your formula gives five.

Comment: The issue is that it can't be $i$ in $i+1$ ways, for example there is only one way to make $2n$. Keep in mind that the numbers are between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: oh i see.Could you kindly suggest what will b the correct approach

Comment: for sum $\leq N$ it will be $(i+)^2.$ The question then is what to do for $l+m >N$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the numbers are between $0$ and $N$, so you overcounted. If $0\le i\le N$, there are $i+1$ ways to make $i$. If $i=N+k$ for $1\le k\le n$, there are $N-k+1$ ways :$(k,N), (k+1, N-1), \cdots, (N,k)$. So we want
$$\sum_{i=0}^N (i+1)^2+\sum_{i=N+1}^{2N}(2N-i+1)^2$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^N(i+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^N (i+1)^2$$
By a popular formula, $\sum_{i=0}^N (i+1)^2=\frac{(N+1)(N+2)(2N+3)}{6}$, so the answer is $\frac{(N+1)(N+2)(2N+3)}{3}-1$.

Comment: lots of thanks for clearing the confusion and correcting my solution

Comment: The limits for the second summation should be from $0$ to $N-1$, making the term that's being subtracted in the answer $(N+1)^2$ rather than 1.

Comment: For $N=1$, this formula gives nine, but isn't the correct answer six, as I worked out in a comment on the original question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes A.J. is right, I'm not in a position where I can edit it right now though.